# Remaster “contextual” synonym

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

If remastering means to remake an audio or video recording of better quality with new technologies, then what’s the equivalent verb for remaking a document or publication i.e. book with new technologies? For example, the formal document could be a lot better in pictures and formatting, but there is a new technology that can make things a lot better looking and formatted.

Comment: Your own term *reformat* works. If video and music etc are added, it is *remade*, another term you’ve used.

Comment: I meant to say, he used an old technology with an old software tool, and I would like to *remake* it with a new one, as I am doing it from scratch. I think *remake* a file (without music and video) makes sense as well.

Answer (score 1):

**reissue (v.)**

> Make a new supply or different form of (a product, especially a book
> or record) available for sale.
>
> *The book was **reissued** with a new epilogue.* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/reissue)

> To issue (something, esp. printed or recorded matter) again,
> frequently in a different form. OED

**reissue (n.)**

> The second or renewed issuing of something, esp. of a book, record,
> film, or other publication; an instance of this; (also) a book, etc.,
> that has been issued again, frequently in a different form. OED

---

> When Mikhailov's book was **reissued** in 1949, the “revised and
> completed” edition underwent some interesting shifts.” [Thomas
> Lahusen; *How Life Writes the Book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gu2YDwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA28&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&f=false)

> It wasn't until 2011, however, that the book [*From Here to Eternity]*
> was **reissued** with the gay content restored. [Hugh Ryan; *When
> Brooklyn Was Queer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZZ9aDwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA227&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&f=false)

> Interestingly, his 1947 book was **reissued** in different formats in 2014
> (paperback), 2015 (hardcover) and 2017 (kindle). [Vincent Palamara;
> *Who's Who in the Secret Service*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Po9oDwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT123&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20formatting&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20formatting&f=false)

> Two years later the book was **reissued** with a new cover image – a
> child on a swing – aimed at a summer reading market. [G. Clark and A.
> Phillips; *Inside Book Publishing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pz33DwAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA253&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20formatting&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20formatting&f=false)

> When the book was **reissued** with additional material in 1985, it
> sold more than 200,000 copies in less than a year. [Carol Kort; *A to
> Z of American Women Writers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QyvXLgnTNpIC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA146&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22&f=false)

> The book was **reissued** in an expanded edition the following decade in
> which Le Corbusier analysed the use of the Modulor system in the Unité
> building... [Tom Allbeson; *Photography, Reconstruction and the
> Cultural History of the Postwar European City*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BNoBEAAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA132&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20photographs&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20photographs&f=false)

> The book was **reissued** in a revised and reformatted new edition
> under the title *A guide to the birds of Fiji and Western Polynesia,
> including American Samoa, Niue, Samoa, Tokelau, Tonga ...* [Martin
> Daly; *Tonga*](https://books.google.com/books?id=OY0BEAAAQBAJ&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA52&dq=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20reformatted&hl=en&source=newbks_fb#v=onepage&q=%22book%20was%20reissued%22%20reformatted&f=false)

> The **reissue** of the book also includes a DVD of Meiselas's 1991
> documentary *Pictures from a Revolution* ... [*American Photo*, vol.
> 19, n.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=dtzlm4wKIyoC&pg=PA12&dq=reissue%20of%20the%20book%20with%20photographs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj266-OjZH0AhUkrHIEHZfACG84ChDoAXoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=reissue%20of%20the%20book%20with%20photographs&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

The normal publishing term is *revising*. *Revision* applies to reformatting, to the insertion of new material, to the correction of errors and to any other aspects that do not detract substantially from the nature, content and purposes of the original.

> **revision**
>
> the process of changing a document, book, etc. in order to improve it, correct mistakes, or make it contain the most recent information
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revision?q=Revision)

Comment: *Revision* normally implies that the changes were made to the substance of the document, and nor merely to the font, layout, and suchlike. Remastering a sound recording seems more analogous to the latter than to the former.